# how to create 2 pdf files at the same time with ghostscript?

Tags: c#, ghostscript

How can I create 2 pdf files at the same time using GhostScript?

this is my code:

```
string gsPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.26\bin\gswin32.exe";

                List gsArgsList = new List();
                gsArgsList.Add(" -dPDFA=2");
                gsArgsList.Add(" -dBATCH");
                gsArgsList.Add(" -dNOPAUSE");                
                gsArgsList.Add(" -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK");
                gsArgsList.Add(" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite");
                gsArgsList.Add(" -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1");
                gsArgsList.Add(" -sOutputFile=" + nuevo);
                gsArgsList.Add(" " + rutaPdfNormal); 

                var gsArgs = String.Join(null, gsArgsList);

                string gs = gsPath + gsArgs;
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(gsPath, gsArgs);
```

Comment: You could create two threads (using Tasks) which are both generating PDFs

Comment: I want to do it with a single invocation to ghostscript

Comment: why do you care about that?

Comment: P.S. To clarify, by "at once" do you mean "in parallel, simultaneously", or just "one after the other without issuing more commands"?

Comment: in parallel, simultaneously

Comment: ok well then you'd need to run two instances in separate threads. I don't see any way round that. Ghostscript can't do that within the executable AFAIK. What's your objection to doing so, exactly?

Comment: ghostscript says that 2 can be created at the same time but I don't know how to do it

Comment: have you got a link to some documentation where it says that (then we can all check it and see exactly what is being discussed)? Surely if it states that, it also gives an example command? And also, are you sure it doesn't just mean sequentially, rather than simultaneously?

Comment: this is the link: https: //www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Output_device and
you can search the section with this: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Output_device

Comment: Do you mean the bit where it says _"For example, in order to create two PDF files from a single invocation of ghostscript the following can be used:"_ ? Well, there's an example shown right after that statement. But as I understand it a) that will create two files from the same source PDF - not sure if that's what you want? and b) this will write the files sequentially. I could potentially be wrong though - have you tested it?

Comment: I have not tried it because I do not know how to use the command

Comment: Well I suggest trying it from the command line directly first, to be sure it works how you want it to. But using it in c# shouldn't be hard either - it's just a string, same as any other command. You should be able to run it the same way as the command you've already shown above. Did you try? It's unclear what specifically you think the problem is with this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create two PDF files simultaneously in a single instance of Ghostscript. The pdfwrite device (which writes the PDF file) only writes to a single file.

I also cannot see the point in writing two files at the same time; perhaps if you explained what you were trying to achieve it might be possible to advise further.

The example you linked to above isn't writing two PDF files simultaneously. It starts by writing to the output file 'tiger.pdf' running the input file 'tiger.eps'. Then it switches to the output file 'colorcir.pdf' and runs the file 'colorcir.ps'. That's not simultaneous, it's sequential; it's exactly the same as running Ghostscript twice with different command lines.